# If PHP's mt_rand() uses a faster algorithm than rand(), why not just change rand() to use the newer implementation?

Tags: php

The purpose of a random number function is to get -- you guessed it -- a random number, something you cannot predict (or be very hard to predict with certainty). If the `mt_rand()` function is faster and less predictable (more "random") than the old `rand()`, why not just switch the underlying implementation to the new method?

To put it another way, what kind of program that uses `rand()` would break in a later version of PHP if/because the underlying implementation changed?

Comment: As noted by Farhad's answer: `Finally as of PHP 7.1, Both rand() and mt_rand() are the same function.` Thus, any code that WAS depending on and using srand, would have changed results in 7.1+. As demonstrated here: https://3v4l.org/IpsHb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mainly because that's *the PHP way*. Just like they added `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of replacing `mysql_escape_string` with it.

However, it might also be related to the disadvantages the mersenne-twister algorithm has (I have no clue if they are also present in the `rand()` algorithm though):

> The algorithm in its native form is not suitable for cryptography (unlike Blum Blum Shub). Observing a sufficient number of iterates (624 in the case of MT19937, since this figure is the size of the state vector from which future iterates are produced) allows one to predict all future iterates. A pair of cryptographic stream ciphers based on output from Mersenne twister has been proposed by Makoto Matsumoto et al. The authors claim speeds 1.5 to 2 times faster than Advanced Encryption Standard in counter mode. <sup>[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Disadvantages)</sup>
>
> Another issue is that it can take a long time to turn a non-random initial state (notably the presence of many zeros) into output that passes randomness tests. A small lagged Fibonacci generator or linear congruential generator gets started much more quickly and usually is used to seed the Mersenne Twister with random initial values. <sup>[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Disadvantages)</sup>

Comment: +1 for "the PHP way." Reminds me of Jeff Atwood: "PHP is the result of an [explosion at the function factory](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/php-sucks-but-it-doesnt-matter.html)."

Answer (score 3):

Both algorithms are pseudo-random. That implies that knowing the initial conditions makes it possible to know all future iterations. It is impossible to know if someone relies on such implementation details (i.e. relying on the *implementation* of the function instead of on the *intent* of the function), and it is therefore safer to create a new function.

Comment: Some games are also a good example. If the RNG is initialized with a seed received from the server the client can do calculations on its own and the server can still validate them. That would horribly fail if the algorithm was changed at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Finally as of PHP 7.1, Both `rand()` and `mt_rand()` are the same function.